# Getting the error while updating GWT 2.5.1 to 2.9.0 and sencha GXT 3.1.1 to 4.1

Tags: java, gwt, gxt

Quick question. Getting below error:

```
Loading inherited module 'com.sencha.gxt.ui.GXT'
     [java]          Loading inherited module 'com.sencha.gxt.data.Data'
     [java]             Loading inherited module 'com.sencha.gxt.core.Core'
     [java]                [ERROR] Line 107: Value 'ie8' in not a valid value for property 'user.agent'
```

using GWT 2.9.0, Sencha GXT 4.1 and Java11.
So, if any one can help me figuring out, how do I resolve this error?

Comment: Are you sure, that you are using GWT 2.9.0. This error message usually happens when using GXT with GWT 2.10.0 and newer.

Comment: Yes sure I am using GWT 2.9.0.
Before this error I am facing this below issue, do you have any idea on this?
   
  [java]                Loading inherited module 'com.google.gwt.http.HTTP'
     [java]                   Loading inherited module 'com.google.gwt.user.Timer'
     [java]                      [ERROR] Line 19: Unexpected exception while processing element 'source'
     [java] java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/tools/ant/types/ZipScanner
     [java]  at com.google.gwt.dev.resource.impl.DefaultFilters.getScanner(DefaultFilters.java:240)

Comment: Are you using MAven? Check for multiple versions of an dependency.

Comment: No, using Gradle. I checked there is no multiple dependency. Is there any command or any way we can check for multiple dependency.

Comment: Use `mvn dependency:tree -Dverbose` to look for the full list of what version of which jar is present, and to list conflicts from what is requested. The NoClassDefFound for ZipScanner is another hint that you've got your classpath mixed up somehow.

Comment: I am using gradle, any command in gradle to check multiple dependency?

Answer (score 0):

Refer to docs, you might find something that you are missing in your upgrade process

https://docs.sencha.com/gxt/4.x/guides/getting_started/maven/Maven.html
https://docs.sencha.com/gxt/4.x/guides/getting_started/migration/Migration3to4.html